# In Rails, how do I print out a user.name from an Active Record left join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have Users and Albums tables. The foreign key for the Albums table is the `user_id`.

My Active Record query is:

```
def show
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  @added_by = User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN albums ON albums.id = (params[:id])')
end
```

In my ERB I have:

```
<%= added_by.name %>
```

My schema is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150930203820) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "artist",     null: false
    t.integer  "year"
    t.string   "title",      null: false
    t.string   "pressing"
    t.string   "format"
    t.string   "label"
    t.string   "genre"
    t.text     "image_url"
    t.string   "tracklist"
    t.string   "country"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.boolean  "favorite"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "albums", ["user_id"], name: "index_albums_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                      null: false
    t.string   "pic_url"
    t.string   "name",                       null: false
    t.string   "favorite"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "last_login_at"
    t.datetime "last_logout_at"
    t.datetime "last_activity_at"
    t.string   "last_login_from_ip_address"
  end

  add_index "users", ["last_logout_at", "last_activity_at"], name: "index_users_on_last_logout_at_and_last_activity_at", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["name", "email"], name: "index_users_on_name_and_email", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "albums", "users"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have no idea how to input code in here and maintain formatting." Perhaps reading the "help" for the editor used to enter your question would provide you the answers.

Comment: Thanks. Will do next time.

Comment: The join doesn't make any sense. Can you describe what you're trying to do in more detail?

Comment: Are you trying to print out the user.name from an album? Have you set up an has_many, belongs_to relationship? As in, a user has_many albums? (That seems to be like what you're trying to set up.) If that's the case, then you should be able to call album.user.name.

Comment: <%= @added_by.name %>

Comment: I don't think you want an outer join. An outer join will also return users without an album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Try:

```
@album.user.name
```

If this now work then **Make sure** you have set **[Active Record Associations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)** in models like:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
end
# album.rb
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```